# Like a Photo with fb.api

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-like, photo

I've trying to post a like in a photo on behalf of a user when they click an image on my app, so far I know that I have to ask for publish_stream permission and send a post to the fb.api like this (fb.api(PHOTO_ID/likes,post,function(response){}); my problem is that every time I click on a image the result on the post method is true but the like on the photo it's never achieved, my code is this:

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{
  if(response)  {
      var cadena = photoId + '/likes';
      FB.api(cadena, 'post', function(result) {
          console.dir(result);
      });
  }
}, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions